# c# wpf combobox average

Tags: c#, wpf

I want a simple code for my project , when i click in button average                        in textbox should appear the average of selected numbers in all combobox

```
          <ComboBox Name="cbnota6" Margin="0,9,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="cbnota7" Margin="0,9,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="cbnota8" Margin="0,9,0,0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        </ComboBox>
           <Button Name="btnmesatarja" Content="Mesatarja" Width="80" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="btnmesatarja_Click" />
        <TextBox Name="txtmesatarja" Width="100" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
```

So could someone of you tell how to do that what i asked

Comment: you asked this question and i gave you a response, a working example. don`t understand why you post again, same question

Comment: because it didnt work :(

Comment: I think you are not able to do a copy paste. my solution is tested. down vote from me.

Comment: i dont know where did you test it, ive said before, i tried this code that you gave me , but it didnt work sorry :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to traverse through each combobox to get the sum of all the items inside those comboboxes, keep it saved in a variable along with the count of all items in those comboboxes.

Something like

```
int intCBAverage;
int intCBSum = 0;
int intCBCount = 0;
foreach (var item in cbnota6.Items) 
{
    intCBSum += int.Parse(item.ToString());
    intCBCount++;
}

foreach (var item in cbnota7.Items) 
{
    intCBSum += int.Parse(item.ToString());
    intCBCount++;
}

foreach (var item in cbnota8.Items) 
{
    intCBSum += int.Parse(item.ToString());
    intCBCount++;
}

intCBAverage = intCBSum / intCBCount;
```

The above piece of code is just for illustration of the idea. Hope you got the idea.

Once you have the average, you can show that in the textbook.

Also, instead of looping through each combobox you can loop through each control in the form, check whether the control is a combobox or not and if yes, then loop through the combobox items. Something like

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is ComboBox)
  {
    foreach (var item in x.Items)
    {
        intCBSum += int.Parse(item.ToString());
        intCBCount++;
    }
  }
}
```